# Nativescript Binding: Property: 'name' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'name'

Tags: listview, data-binding, nativescript

i am trying to create a listview to show data from hardcoded array list and its working good , but i need to make user able to click on any item to show the details of this item in another page , how can i do that ? i tried to create another array for details and make bindingContext and its working good but i receive this error message in console :

```
Binding: Property: 'name' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'name'
```

thats my code :

main-view-model.js:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

function RegisterViewModel() {
    var viewModel = new Observable();
    viewModel.shows = [
        {name:"Reg1"},
        {name:"Reg2"},
        {name:"Reg3"},
        {name:"Reg4"},
        {name:"Reg5"},


    ];

    return viewModel;

}

exports.RegisterViewModel = RegisterViewModel;
```

main-page.js:

```
var RegisterViewModel = require("./main-view-model").RegisterViewModel;
var frameModule = require('ui/frame'); 


var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
function RegisterViewModel(args) {
var page = args.object;
page.bindingContext = RegisterViewModel();
}

exports.getInfo = function (args) {
     var navigationEntry = { 
     moduleName: "RegisterDetails",
     context: {info:args.view.bindingContext}
      }
      frameModule.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);
    }

exports.loaded = function(args){
    args.object.bindingContext = viewModel;
}


exports.RegisterViewModel = RegisterViewModel;
```

main-page.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page" loaded="loaded">

    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>

    <StackLayout class="p-20">

 <SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search" text="" clear="onClear" submit="onSubmit" />
<TabView>
   <TabView.items>
     <TabViewItem title="register">
       <TabViewItem.view>
           <ListView items="{{shows}}" tap="getInfo" >

            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{name}}" />

            </ListView.itemTemplate>

       </ListView>
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
     <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
       <TabViewItem.view>
          <Label text="Label in Tab2" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
   </TabView.items>
 </TabView>

    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

these for details:

RegisterDetails-model.js

```
    viewModel.shows = [
        {name:"Reg01"},
        {name:"Reg02"},
        {name:"Reg03"},
        {name:"Reg04"},
        {name:"Reg05"},

    ];
    return gotData;

}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

RegisterDetails.js:

```
var gotData;
function pageLoaded(args) {
     var page = args.object;
     gotData = page.navigationContext.info;
     page.bindingContext={passedData:gotData}
    }

    exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

RegisterDetails.xml:

```
 <Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page" loaded="pageLoaded">

        <Page.actionBar>
            <ActionBar title="Register" icon="" class="action-bar">
            </ActionBar>
        </Page.actionBar>

        <StackLayout >
                    <Label text="{{name}}"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </Page>
```

but when i clicked on any item i go to register details but no data shows in page , and i received   this message error in console :

```
JS: Binding: Property: 'name' is invalid or does not exist. SourceProperty: 'name'
```

any help?

Comment: Where is the variable `name` referenced in your `RegisterDetails.js` file? You are referencing it in the `RegisterDetails.xml` file, but don't appear to have defined it. Also per the docs, the tap event for the ListView should be `itemTap` instead of `tap`.

Comment: How to add 'name' property in RegisterDetails ? i used 'var gotdata' to access 'name' property , what you suggest ?